# MQ MFT file name with separator

Tags: websphere-mq-fte

We have chosen '.' as separator in MQ MFT interface with following condition

1. User writes text file (.txt)
2. Once they completed writing, they place .trg file with zero bytes
3. Our monitor identifies the trg file, it search txt file with same name.

The following names work as expected:

```
Sample_text_file.trg  
Sample_text_file.txt
```

Issue: The monitor fails to trigger if the filename contains more than one '.' . For example,

```
Sample.text_file.trg
```

It is searching txt file with name `Sample.txt` instead of `Sample.text_file.txt`.

Can you please advise me to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you please describe how you created your monitor and transfer template?

Comment: I don't believe the 'mft' tag means what you think it does.  While websphere supports "Managed File Transfer", the MFT tag is for [Media Foundation Transforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms703138%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The question asks for help debugging MQ MFT's regex but fails to provide the syntax used to specify the regex.  I'm with Tim on this one - please post the monitor definition if you would like a reasonably correct answer rather than a wild guess.